# Can we create and access a registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE without running application with admin permissions in C#

Tags: c#, registry

Is there any possibility to create a key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with out running the application in admin mode. If a key is not there then a new key should be created. If a key already exists it should be returned. I tried below code but it is not working. Any Ideas?

```
RegistryKey subRegKey = null;
string regVal = "";

try
{
   subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(registryBit, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
   regVal = subRegKey == null ? string.Empty : (string)subRegKey.GetValue(registryKey);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error :");
    Console.WriteLine("  : " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
 }
```

Hi Damien, 
I have tried below as per your suggestions but could not succeed. Can you help?

As per your suggestion i have created 4 parent nodes by running a console application in admin mode in below ways,

```
subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK1\Default");
subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK2\Default",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK3\ReadSubTree",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK4\ReadWriteSubTree",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

and i tried to create sub keys on each of those parent nodes in below 4 ways from a console application (with out adminstrator),

```
subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK1\Default");
subRegKey =
```

Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK1\Default",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
    subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK1\Default",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
    subRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\DMK1\Default",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

But none of them created a subkey on parent key. If possible can you help me out what is the way to create parent and child nodes using C# code?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but.

Keys have permissions. It's certainly possible for a particular key somewhere in the tree descending from HKLM to have it's permissions set so that anyone can create values/subkeys within it.

For a specific application, this ought to be a (sub)key created specifically for this purpose, during software installation. Of course, the installation has to be performed by an administrator.

In an ad-hoc fashion, an administrator can create such a key and tell you about it.

But in general, the HKLM tree is meant for *machine wide* settings, and most of those are *properly* under the control of the machine's administrators. Most users should *not* be able to apply machine-wide setting changes, except for specifically scoped/anticipated changes for particular applications, which are covered by my above description.

Comment: What should be the Permissions value for that folder which represents the tree?

Comment: Hi Damien i have tried your solution in C# in above mentioned ways. Can you let me know i you find any thing wrong any thing i missed to try? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally your software should not need to write into the HKLM hive. I cannot think of any reason to do so.

Maybe you are about to try to handle software setup within your App. You should leverage a setup program instead (WiX toolset for instance).

Maybe you would like to share some state information. Use %PROGRAMDATA% for this.

Secretly trying to alter machine wide configuration programmatically is an administrators nightmare and could be considered being malware behavior.

Comment: My project is 20 years old legacy application written over millions of lines. It migrated from VB Script to .Net and with 5 years effort.I know with .Net they could have used config files but i can not change it now. All i need solution to my specific problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was working after i changed "Changed User Account Control Settings" to never notify and restarted the machine to take the changes effect. After that i was able to create keys in custom software folder.